# How do I solve exponential equation in symbolic form using Lambertw

Tags: matlab, optimization

Assume that A, B and C are positive constants. I need to solve the following equation in symbolic form as W(A,B,C).

`solve(x-(exp(log(2)*x*A)-B)*C==0)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the equation mixes polynomials and transcendentals, my first thought was simply that it may not have an analytical solution.  However, the form reminded me of the Lambert W function ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and [Mathworks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/09/02/the-lambert-w-function/)), so I tried the variable substitution `u = x/c+b` which yields the simplified problem

```matlab
solve(u == alpha * exp(beta * u) , u);
```

where `alpha = exp(-log(2)*a*b*c)` and `beta = log(2)*a*c`.  Running this through Matlab gives me

```matlab
>> syms alpha beta u
>> solve(u == alpha * exp(beta * u) , u)
ans =
-lambertw(0, -alpha*beta)/beta
```

which indeed showcases a  Lambert W function call.  With this knowledge, we can get the solution in terms of `xsol` like so:

```matlab
syms a b c alpha beta x u xsol usol
usol = solve(u == alpha * exp(beta*u),u);
log2 = log(sym(2));
xsol = subs(c*(usol-b),[alpha,beta],[exp(-log2*a*b*c),log2*a*c]);
```

---

Let's make sure the Symbolic Engine didn't make a mistake by checking the analytical solution against a numeric one:

```matlab
anum = rand();
bnum = rand();
cnum = rand();
xana = double(subs(xsol,[a,b,c],[anum,bnum,cnum]));
xnum = vpasolve(x-(exp(log2*x*anum)-bnum)*cnum,x);
fprintf('%15.10e\n%15.10e\n%15.10e\n',xana,xnum,xana-xnum);
```

which displays

```matlab
8.0171933677e-02
8.0171933677e-02
1.7453177064e-19
```

**Note**: certain combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c` may result in an equation with no real solution.  In such situations, the analytical solution may give a complex number whose veracity should be highly questioned.

Comment: Thank you! Considering the Lambert call in matlab, is that correct to define `x = (-c) [W(alpha*beta)/beta+b]` where `W(x)` is a solution for `W(x)exp(W(x))=x` so as to define an explicit symbolic representation? Does it convey the same thing to reader? @troyhaskin